# Secure Socket Agent Proxies listener Error

Tags: redhat

I try to run the server for ssa by using `ssaserver&` command but I face this error on my server machine
from yesterday.

> Error creating listening socket at [host name : port number] the network address may be in use.

I really don't know why it is showing this error and how can be the address in use.

My OS is RedHat7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really happen because you maybe closed your terminal or logged out from current user account in RedHat.

To solve this issue you can use this command here:

```
ps -ef|grep ssaserver
```

Which will show you if the service ssaserver already in use and from this you can get the service id and child ids.

You can then kill the service id by using kill command:

```
kill #(serviceid)
```

Here is a link to show you how to use kill command: [Link_1](https://linuxize.com/post/kill-command-in-linux/)

But you can face this problem again and again so I think it will be fine if you will use `nohup` command to run the service you need.

**Note:** `nohup` is a command used to run a process(job) on a server and have it continue after you have logged out or otherwise lost connection to the server

Such as:

```
nohup ssaserver&
```

Here is extra link for `nohup` examples: [Link_2](https://www.journaldev.com/27875/nohup-command-in-linux)